# Looping over dataframe using multiple columns throwing ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, multi-index

I am trying to apply for loops inside a Pandas dataframe to access two columns at a time. My piece of code works perfectly for a single column. But when applying to multiple columns, it is throwing : "ValueError : too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

My code snippet is as follows -

```
for col1, col2 in df.columns:
    if col1.startswith('ColumnName1') and col2.startswith('ColumnName2') and df[col2].notnull()*1:
        new_df = df.groupby([col1, col2]).agg({'ColumnName3': 'unique'}).reset_index()
    elif col1.startswith('ColumnName1') and col2.startswith('ColumnName2') and not df[col2].notnull()*1:
        new_df = df.groupby(col1).agg({'ColumnName3': 'unique'}).reset_index()
```

The small problem is the column names are too large and not under control, because this dataframe has multiheader columns, so after merging they are creating some random filling names. Hence the
".startswith". The column names are much larger.

I am trying to perform a groupby of column 3 based on columns 1 and 2, if column 2 is not null, else a groupby using column1 when column 2 is null.

Can anyone tell me where am I wrong here, or what am I missing here?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the idea. So I think it is not possible to loop over a dataframe like this

Comment: If you must access two columns at a time, perhaps try `for col1, col2 in zip(df.columns, df.columns[1:]):`. This iterates over two parallel lists one of which is the 1-shifted version of the other, and it stops when the shorter exhausts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to loop over `df.columns` two values at a time, you can do so like this:

```
import itertools as it

for col1, col2 in it.zip_longest(*[iter(df.columns)]*2):
    ...
```

We create a list containing an iterator over the columns, and then apply `*2` to get a list with two of that same iterator object. Because it's the same iterator, ever time we iterate over one we also advance the other one. We then zip them together to go from a sequence of 2 items of length `len(df.columns) // 2`, to a sequence with `len(df.columns) // 2` tuples of 2 items.

Comment: This resolved the error. Thanks. Great concept insight too, haven't thought like that

Comment: This is very interesting! Could this be applied for selecting columns that are not successive? For instance, col1 with col101, col2 with col102, or would it be simpler to just rearrange the columns?

Comment: @m_power Yes, you can swap out `df.columns` for any iterable you'd like. Make sure the length of the iterable matches the variables you unpack it into. You can collect extra values by adding a variable with an asterisk in the parameter list like so: `for a, b, *c in ...`. For the use case you're suggesting, the iterable you provide will have to be ordered `col1, col101, col2, col102, ...`.

Comment: @WillDaSilva, And do you think this approach would be faster than simply doing a for loop on the column range (eg `for col in range(df.shape[1]):` and call the right columns inside the loop with `df.iloc[:, col].somefunc(); df.iloc[:, col + 100].somefunc();`?

Comment: @m_power My guess would be that it would be marginally slowler, and less readable too for this use case.

Comment: @WillDaSilva I'll benchmark it and let you know! I'm using more than two columns per iteration, so maybe it would actually be more readable!